# vagrant nginx vhost servername can't in use,only localhost and 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, vagrant

vhost config:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /home/vagrant/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name local.laravel.test;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

local.laravel.test:5000: server DNS address could not be found.

127.0.0.1:5000:ok

Comment: did you edit your host `hosts` file ? and add the line for `local.laravel.test` ?

Comment: Your answer is work. It remind of me something. Ever I didn't edit the host and can access by server_name. For the local Intranet has bound the domain with ip. Thank you!